# What's causing my "No space for directory leaf checksum" error?

Tags: server, raid, ext4, mdadm, nvme

I have a new Ubuntu 20.04 HPE DL360 Gen10 server to replace an old 16.04 HPE DL360 Gen9 server for running Graphite and Grafana. The old server had a 2 TB hardware RAID10 (4 x 1 TB SSDs) ext4 filesystem for the whisper data, while the new server's filesystem is a ~2.1 TB md software RAID10 (6 x 800 GB MZXL5800HBHQ-000H3 NVMe SSDs). The data is about 1.1 million .wsp files spread across about 2.6 million directories (about 9 layers deep in some places).

Trying to access some directories, well after they are created, results in errors like this:

```
find: ‘/data/graphite/whisper/aggro/30d/1m/threads_running_current/dSystem/SysPerfSrv1/10/5/17/32’: Bad message
```

with the following errors in syslog:

```
Dec 21 08:31:34 graphite.example.com kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device md0p1): ext4_dirblock_csum_verify:370: inode #111153487: comm find: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
Dec 21 08:31:34 graphite.example.com kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md0p1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:997: inode #111153487: comm find: Directory block failed checksum
```

This is the second time I've had this problem since building this server over the last couple of months and migrating the data from the old server. The first time, I ran the `e2fsck -y -D /dev/md/0p1` command, which ultimately fixed the filesystem but recovered about 85,000 files or partial files to `lost+found`.

I've verified with HPE that this is not a hardware issue (via submitting an AHS log from the iLO, which also confirmed the disks are at the newest firmware, which was a possible issue based on my research), so I don't know what is causing it. Despite the total number of directories, there are no individual directories with more than 64k immediate child subdirectories, but I'm still not ruling out some kind of file and/or directory limit, though I'd never seen this problem on the previous server, being a hardware raid but also on a 4-year old OS (again, Ubuntu 16.04 vs. 20.04). However, I have a similar server on an AWS EC2 instance with the whisper data on a large EBS volume with similar file and directory numbers and I've not seen the problem there either.

Any suggestions in further troubleshooting ideas?

EDIT: Filesystem data and inode usage and free, as requested:

```
root at graphite in ~ # df -lhi /data/graphite
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md0p1       140M  3.8M  136M    3% /data/graphite

root at graphite in ~ # df -lh /data/graphite
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0p1      2.2T  580G  1.5T  28% /data/graphite
```

EDIT: Further possibly useful info, gist showing output of `tune2fs -l /dev/md0p1`: https://gist.github.com/justinclloyd/9b23227015bc6589cb4c226885226d84

EDIT 2: After recreating the filesystem (but not the software raid device), copying the 540 GB data back from the live system, and letting it sit for a while with very little I/O (only the server itself is writing graphite metrics, and not receiving any from other servers), I have now seen the "Bad message" and other errors reoccurring and to directories that have not been written. This is leading me to believe the problem is really with the software raid somehow, perhaps combined with Graphite's write I/O patterns, though I have no real way to confirm this.

EDIT 3: A troubleshooting recommendation I received was to try a different filesystem type, such as XFS or ZFS. I've gone ahead and deleted the mdadm array and created a ZFS pool with the disks and a filesystem in the pool and then copied back the data and I'm letting Graphite run now (albeit with very little I/O) to see if the problem comes back.

EDIT 4: While I never figured out why the ext4 mdadm-based filesystem was getting these corruption isses, moving to ZFS seems to have eliminated the problem after a few weeks of monitoring it.