# Permanently deleting an mdadm array created during OS installation

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.1 server with 6 NVMe SSDs that were configured as raid10 mdadm array md0. In order to troubleshoot my [Graphite filesystem corruption problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301876/whats-causing-my-no-space-for-directory-leaf-checksum-error), I'm trying to use ZFS instead of ext4. I stopped the md0 array via `mdadm --manage --stop /dev/md0` so I could create a zpool, but the array keeps getting recreated within a few seconds as md127 by a `/sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan` process, and I see a `[md127_raid10]` kernel thread that is managing the array.

Here are my [/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf](https://gist.github.com/justinclloyd/ac6bd0e887107e76ede98bc0b8fbefde) and [/etc/default/mdadm](https://gist.github.com/justinclloyd/0b17fd0110e3678350e98b15864054f7) files, untouched from their default contents. Here is the [detail output for md127](https://gist.github.com/justinclloyd/9207ccbbc6dc113e36dd297cb0bca120).

How do I properly (i.e. according to Ubuntu and mdadm design principles and not just adding hacking a script as I've seen in other questions and blog posts, etc.) completely remove the metadevice so I can reuse the disks in a ZFS pool?

Comment: `mdadm --zero-superblock`

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I did have to run that as well in-between the `mdadm --stop` and `update-initramfs` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I learned of a simple and reasonable solution from one of our VAR solutions engineers, which was to temporarily append the following line to mdadm.conf to ignore the array, first getting its uuid from mdadm and colon-separating it as indicated, and then running the `mdadm --manage --stop` command followed by `update-initramfs -u`.

```
ARRAY <ignore> UUID=2e69e366:2002beea:811ff014:8dce9e33
```